# How to calculate moving average incrementally with daily data added to data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have daily data and want to calculate 5 days, 30 days and 90 days moving average per user and write out to a CSV.  New data comes in everyday.  How do I calculate these averages for the new data only, assuming I will load the data frame with last 89 days data plus today's data.

date         user       daily_sales 5_days_MA 30_days_MV 90_days_MV
2019-05-01   1           34
2019-05-01   2           20
....

2019-07-18   .....

The number of rows per day is about 1 million. If data for 90days is too much, 30 days is OK

Comment: Let us know what have you tried out so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `rolling()` method on your dataset if it's in DataFrame format.

```
your_df['MA_30_days'] = df[where_to_apply].rolling(window = 30).mean()
```

If you need different window on which moving average will be calculated just change `window` parameter. In my example I used `mean()` to calculate but you can choose some other statistic as well.

This code will create another column named *'MA_30_days'* with calculated moving average in your DataFrame.

You can also create another DataFrame where you will collect and loop over your dataset to calculate all moving averages and save it to CSV format as you wanted.

```
your_df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

In your case to calculation should be consider only the newest data. If you want to perform this on latest data just slice it. However the very first rows will be `NaN` (depends on `window`).

```
df[where_to_apply][-90:].rolling(window = 30).mean()
```

This will calculate moving average on last 90 rows of specific column in some df and first 29 rows would be `NaN`. If your latest 90 rows should be all meaningful data than you can start calculation earlier than on last 90 rows - depends on `window` size.

Answer (score 0):

if the df already contains yesterday's moving average, and just the new day's Simple MA is required, I would say use this approach:

```
MAlength=90
df.loc[day-1:'MA']=(
                    (df.loc[day-1:'MA']*MAlength) #expand yesterday's MA value
                     -df.loc[day-MAlength:'Price']  #remove oldest price
                     +df.loc[day-MAlength:'Price']  #add newest price
                   )/MAlength   #re-average
```